# Why I get this error in haml: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

Can some one please explain why I get this error:

```
app/views/students/registrations/new.html.haml:28: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Extracted source (around line #28):

25: = render :partial => "devise/shared/links"
```

Here is the form:

```
%h2 Sign up
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  %div
    = f.label :email
    %br/
    = f.email_field :email
  %div
    = f.label :password
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password
  %div
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation

  %p
    = f.label 'country', 'Country'
      %span
        (displayed in your articles / comments)
    = f.select :country_id, @countries
  %div= f.submit "Sign up"
= render :partial => "devise/shared/links"
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with `= f.select :country_id, @countries` ..Can you show us your controller code for the `registrations#new` action, please?  Also, the `resource` does have all of these model attributes, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your nesting inside of the label at the following lines:

```
= f.label 'country', 'Country'
  %span
    (displayed in your articles / comments)
```

Try changing it to

```
= f.label 'country', 'Country'
%span (displayed in your articles / comments)
```

and styling a different way.